# Return function and from file.type and import Issues on PyCham

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I am currently learning to build a racing game with pygame and assets from TechwithTim on Youtube(URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ktUWfAMPg&t=1119s).

It seems like 2 problems are happing.

1. in my utils file which I am using to scale_image the return is outside the function

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.examples.sprite_texture import img
    
    def scale_image(img, factor):
        size = round(img.get_width()  * factor), round(img.get_height()  * factor)
    
    return pygame.transform.scale(img, size)
```

Secondly, My main file is not recognizing

```
from utils import scale_image
```

**Versions**
Python 3.9,

Pygame 2.1.0

PyCharm Community Edition

Hope to find a solution soon
from a young inexperienced programmer

Comment: Yes, your `return` is outside of your function.  So, indent it so that is INSIDE of your function.  Is your file called `utils`, or is it called `utils.py`, which is what it needs to be?

Comment: its called utils.py

Comment: And is it in the same folder as your main file?

Answer (score -1):

Try to reimport the pygame.

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pygame
```

Comment: would i do that in cmd or terminal of pycharm?

Comment: Why do you think that would make any difference at all to his problem?

Comment: I use Pycharm on daily basis and just a few days ago when I was making a game with pygame there were some import errors and reinstalling the module fixed it. Here is my game project that i made from the same YouTuber. So, I thought this might fix it for him too.
https://github.com/simarsudo/PySpaceInvadors

Comment: Secondly, return pygame.transform.scale(img, size) was outside of the function, so I thought there were some errors while during the installation of the module.

Comment: @MrAmericaninUK run it from Pycharm.

Comment: ok thanks it fixed now